# Export nested dictionary to csv

Tags: python-3.x, loops, csv

I need to export a nested dictionary to CSV. Here's what each entry looks like (that needs to be one line in the csv later):

```
{'createdTime': '2017-10-30T12:33:02.000Z',
 'fields': {'Date': '2017-10-30T12:32:56.000Z',
            'field1': 'example@gmail.com',
            'field2': 1474538185964188,
            'field3': 6337,
            ....},
 'id': 'reca7LBr64XM1ClWy'}
```

I think I need to iterate through the dictionary and create a list of lists(?) to create the csv from using the csv module.

```
['Date', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3', ...],
['2017-10-30T12:32:56.000Z', 'example@gmail.com', 1474538185964188, 6337 ...]
```

My problem is to find a smart way to iterate through the dict to get to a list like this.

Comment: Does it strictly have to be csv? JSON or yaml would be a much better fit for nested dicts.

Comment: How about put `id` before `fields`. Then you can just have the dict fields be anything after the first two

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be csv (it's for an external partner that need to have it in that format) and there's no chance to alter the dict, it's how it is coming from a database that can't be changed anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values in the below way:

```
def process_data():

    csv_data = [{'createdTime': '2017-10-30T12:33:02.000Z',
                'fields': {'Date': '2017-10-30T12:32:56.000Z',
                'field1': 'example@gmail.com',
                'field2': 1474538185964188,
                'field3': 6337},
              'id': 'reca7LBr64XM1ClWy'},
              {'createdTime': '2017-10-30T12:33:02.000Z',
                'fields': {'Date': '2017-10-30T12:32:56.000Z',
                'field1': 'example@gmail.com',
                'field2': 1474538185964188,
                'field3': 6337},
              'id': 'reca7LBr64XM1ClWy'}]


    headers = [key for key in csv_data[0]['fields'].keys()]

    body = []
    for row in csv_data:
        body_row = []
        for colomn_header in headers:
            body_row.append(row['fields'][colomn_header])
        body.append(body_row)

process_data()

#header -- ['Date', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3']
#body -- [['2017-10-30T12:32:56.000Z', 'example@gmail.com', 
#         1474538185964188, 6337], ['2017-10-30T12:32:56.000Z', 
#         'example@gmail.com', 1474538185964188, 6337]]
```